# Handling multi-valued parameter in DB2 Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have a Stored Procedure with a input param, which is a multi valued parameter of Varchar.
The passed parameters are passed to the IN Clause of the query.
I am unable to figure out how to handle that in the stored procedure.
Till now , I have this (this is the snippet of the actual stored procedure) :

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE <SCHEMA>.Some_Proc
(
 IN V_INDSTRY_DESCRPTN VARCHAR (2000)


)
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
DECLARE WHERE_CLAUSE VARCHAR(5000) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE OUTER_CLAUSE VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE V_SQL VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE CSR_RSLT_SET CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR S1;
IF (V_INDSTRY_DESCRPTN != 'ALL') THEN 
SET WHERE_CLAUSE = WHERE_CLAUSE || 'AND industry.INDSTRY_DESCRPTN in ( '''||V_INDSTRY_DESCRPTN||''')'  ;
END IF; 
SET V_SQL ='<SOME QUERY>'
/*some other logic goes here*/
PREPARE S1 FROM V_SQL;
OPEN CSR_RSLT_SET;
END
```

I am calling the procedure like this :

```
CALL <SCHEMA>.Some_Proc ('industry1')
```

1)how do I send multiple values in the same parameter?
`CALL <SCHEMA>.Some_Proc ("'industry1','industry2'")` gives a compilation error
2)how do I handle the multi-valued parameter within the procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as is:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_MULTIVALUE(P_TABSCHEMAS VARCHAR(128))
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
  DECLARE L_STMT VARCHAR(200);
  DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR S1;

  SET L_STMT = 'SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA IN ('||P_TABSCHEMAS||')';
  CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_STMT);
  PREPARE S1 FROM L_STMT;
  OPEN C1;
END@

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON@

CALL TEST_MULTIVALUE('''SYSCAT''')@
CALL TEST_MULTIVALUE('''SYSCAT'', ''SYSSTAT''')@
```

### For those who are afraid of sql injections

We tokenize the input parameter with strings separated by comma producing a table of strings.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_MULTIVALUE_STATIC(P_TABSCHEMAS VARCHAR(128))
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
  DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME
    FROM SYSCAT.TABLES T
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1
      FROM XMLTABLE 
      (
      'for $id in tokenize($s, "\s*,\s*") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
      passing P_TABSCHEMAS as "s"
      COLUMNS
        TOK VARCHAR(128) PATH '.'
      ) P
      WHERE P.TOK=T.TABSCHEMA
    );
  OPEN C1;
END
@

CALL TEST_MULTIVALUE_STATIC('SYSCAT')@
CALL TEST_MULTIVALUE_STATIC('SYSCAT, SYSSTAT')@
```

Comment: ! You're using straight string concatenation into a statement, which means this is vulnerable to SQL Injection.  This is particularly egregious, because there's a `PREPARE` statement a line down.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your question actually is, how to escape single quotes inside a character literal (surrounded by single quotes) in the standard-compliant SQL. The answer is, by doubling them:

```
CALL <SCHEMA>.Some_Proc ('''industry1'',''industry2''')
```